# Pick non-random object from list Python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to figure out how to pick a string from a list then make that string a variable. For example,

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I want to pick 'c' from the list, so I want to pull the 2nd object (because the first object is 0) and set that object to a variable so if I said

```
print var1
```

it would give me

```
c
```

How would I go about doing this?

Edit: Sorry! I forgot to mention it is in Python 2.7.9.

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: it's the *3rd* object, and its *index* is 2.

Comment: Terribly sorry! I forgot to mention this is python, made an edit.

Comment: Are you trying to get the item based on its value `'c'`, or its index 2? What happened when you tried whatever you tried to do whatever you're doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Let's break it down**:

```
>>> list = [ 'a',       'b',       'c',        'd'  ]
            list[0]   list[1]   >>list[2]<<   list[3] 


>>> var1 = list[2]   #Assign it to var1


>>> print var1       #Now printing var1 would give you 'c'
'c'
```

---

**Note:**

1. Python lists always start indexing at 0
2. Don't use the keyword '`list`' to name a list. Use something else, ex. `my_list`

Answer (score 0):

This is basic indexing:
`var1 = list[2]`
You may want to read through the [Python Tutorial.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can access elements of a list through its zero-based index. You can do it like this:

```
var1 = list[2]
```

Now `var1` is set to `c`.

You can read through [Python's data structures document](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) for a more comprehensive explanation of list behavior.